# How to use exception filter in nest.js

Tags: typescript, exception, nestjs

According to document I developed `nest.js` exception filter.

https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

I'd like to know how to use `catch` function in my `service`

I'd like to apply this `exception filter` to the `service`

As I am beginner. Are there any good way to apply `exceptionfilter` ?

If someone has opinion, please let me know. Thanks

```
import {
  ArgumentsHost,
  Catch,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
  Logger,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

@Catch()
export class HttpExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    console.log("exception",exception.getResponse());
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const status =
      exception instanceof HttpException
        ? exception.getStatus()
        : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    const errorResponse = {
      code: status,
      timestamp: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
      path: request.url,
      method: request.method,
      message: exception.message || null,
      error: exception.Error;
      
    };

    Logger.error(
      `${request.method} ${request.url}`,
      JSON.stringify(errorResponse),
      'ExceptionFilter',
    );

    response.status(status).json(errorResponse);
  }
}
```

My service is folloiwng

```
import { Injectable, InternalServerErrorException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { eventRepository } from 'src/repositories/event.repository';
import { EventRequest } from './dto/event.dto';
import { Event } from 'src/entities/event.entity';
import { InsertResult, Like } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {
  constructor(private readonly eventRepository: eventRepository) {}
  async createEvent(eventParam: EventRequest): Promise<Event> {
    const event = new Event();
    Object.entries(eventParam).forEach(param => {
      event[param[0]] = param[1];
    });
    try {
      const insertResult = await this.eventRepository.insert(event);
      const id = insertResult.identifiers[0].id
      const Result = await this.eventRepository.findOne(id);
      return Result;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First a detail that you've missed:

You have to make your `HttpExceptionFilter` implement `ExceptionFilter`.

Unfortunately there are only three scopes where you can apply such a filter: [method-scoped, controller-scoped, or global-scoped](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#binding-filters). If you want to apply your filter to your service, you will probably want to apply the filter to the controller implementing your `EventService` like this:

```js
@UseFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter())
@Controller()
export class YourEventController {}
```

Answer (score 0):

According from [the official docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#binding-filters), in order to use your `HttpExceptionFilter`, you could bind it at the controller level, like so:

```js
@Post()
@UseFilters(HttpExceptionFilter) // <== here it goes
async createEvent(@Body() eventParam: EventRequest) {
  return await this.eventService.createEvent(eventParam);
}
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work application-wide, with Request scope, like this:

```js
import { Module, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_FILTER } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ExceptionsFilter } from './exceptions.filter';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      scope: Scope.REQUEST,
      useClass: ExceptionsFilter,
    },
  ],
})
export class FiltersModule {}
```